# Udev rule for USB storage device and partitions

Tags: udev

I am trying to set up a udev rule which symlinks `/dev/sda` to `/dev/cm`, `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/cm1` and `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/cm2`. Of course, depending on what else is connected to the computer, instead of `sda`, the device could turn up as `sdb` or anything else. So I have this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a5c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", GROUP="disk", SYMLINK+="cm"
```

This rule matches my device and yields the `/dev/cm` symlink to the correct device node, but not `/dev/cm1` or `/dev/cm2`, even though I can see that `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` have turned up. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a5c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", GROUP="disk", SYMLINK+="cm%n"
```

See? the symlink name is not `cm`, but `cm%n`. Apparently, the `%n` is the name of the partition. For me, this rule yields the following symlinks:

- /dev/cm
- /dev/cm0 (this one points to /dev/sg0, which is apparently the generic SCSI layer)
- /dev/cm1 (points to the first partition)
- /dev/cm2 (points to the second partition)

https://wiki.debian.org/udev is where to go to learn some of this.